# Simple number validation using JavaScript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Is there any simple method in JavaScript / jQuery to check whether the variable is a number or not (preferably without a plugin)? I want to alert whether the variable is a number or not.

Thanks in advance...**`:)`**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995183/how-to-allow-only-numeric-0-9-in-html-inputbox-using-jquery/2403051#2403051

Comment: no.. This is not the repeat of the question mentioned. I am looking to validate without a plugin..

Comment: do accpet ans if it work for you

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend the `isNaN` function to detect numbers, because of the Java Script type coercion.

Ex:

```
isNaN(""); // returns false (is number), a empty string == 0
isNaN(true); // returns false (is number), boolean true == 1
isNaN(false); // returns false (is number), boolean false == zero
isNaN(new Date); // returns false (is number)
isNaN(null); // returns false (is number), null == 0 !!
```

You should also bear in mind that `isNaN` will return false (is number) for floating point numbers.

```
isNaN('1e1'); // is number
isNaN('1e-1'); // is number
```

I would recommend to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric/1830844#1830844) function instead:

```
function isNumber(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

Comment: so what are yo trying to say, do i modify @Pranay Rana's answer??

Comment: I was just trying to say that using isNaN function is not the most "correct" way to check if a string is a number in Java Script.

Comment: is there any other simple way?? can u make me a fiddle?? :)

Comment: You don't like the function I have sugested to use in the answer?

Comment: I like.. Can u demonstrate it with a fiddle??

Comment: @Corneliu, you are VERY patient; too patient probably.

Answer (score 4):

[Checking number using isNaN function](http://www.plus2net.com/javascript_tutorial/math-isnan.php)

```
var my_string="This is a string";
if(isNaN(my_string)){
document.write ("this is not a number ");
}else{document.write ("this is a number ");
}
```

or

Check whether a number is an illegal number:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    document.write(isNaN(5-2)+ "<br />");
    document.write(isNaN(0)+ "<br />");
    document.write(isNaN("Hello")+ "<br />");
    document.write(isNaN("2005/12/12")+ "<br />");

</script>
```

The output of the code above will be:

```
false
false
true
true
```

Comment: hello @Pranay Rana, can u demonstrate it in a fiddle??

Answer (score 1):

Can use below code for this. I would not rely on isNaN() completely. isNaN has shown inconsistent results to me (e.g - isNaN will not detect blank spaces.).

```
//Event of data being keyed in to textbox with class="numericField".
$(".numericField").keyup(function() {
    // Get the non Numeric char that was enetered
    var nonNumericChars = $(this).val().replace(/[0-9]/g, '');                                  
    if(nonNumericChars.length > 0)
        alert("Non Numeric Data entered");
});
```

Comment: Good point, but what happens when the user deletes all the characters in the input?

Comment: nonNumericChars.length will still be zero and the alert will not be thrown. Are you looking for anything else to do with tat event?

Comment: Ah, you're right. I thought I had caught you with an error, but it turns out I was wrong. I like your answer.

Comment: Thats ok. Best part is we can always some way to fix all errors. so if you can find errors, its better I will learn more :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function isDigit(num) {
    if (num.length>1){return false;}
    var string="1234567890";
    if (string.indexOf(num)!=-1){return true;}
    return false;
}
```

You need to loop through the string and call this function for every character

Answer (score 0):

use standard javascript functions

```
isNaN('9')// this will return false
isNaN('a')// this will return true
```